# is there a function "amongst" or equivalent in lodash or JS?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want the function "amongst" or "within" in lodash or JS. The opposite already exists, it is called "includes". Example :

```
_(['a', 42]).includes(42)
```

I would like to write

```
_(42).amongst(['a', 42])
```

Any clues ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `amongst` / `within` function is a version of `_.includes()` with the search `value` 1st and the `collection` 2nd, so you can create one easily by flipping `_.includes()`:

```js
const amongst = _.flip(_.includes)

console.log(amongst(42, ['a', 42]))
console.log(amongst('b', ['a', 42]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

And you can use `_.mixin()` to add it to lodash:

```js
const amongst = _.flip(_.includes)

_.mixin({ amongst });


console.log(_(42).amongst(['a', 42]))
console.log(_('b').amongst(['a', 42]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

In vanillaJS you can create a function that does the same thing:

```js
const amongst = (value, collection) => collection.includes(value)

console.log(amongst(42, ['a', 42]))
console.log(amongst('b', ['a', 42]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```